# Remove rows between 2 df in python and pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this 2 df:

df_history

```
date        codigo_cliente  amount  cliente_ciudad
2021-03-09  219381          31893   JSFLA
2021-03-09  4341421         43243   AFADS
2021-03-09  134241          453454  FAFDS
2021-03-08  43497592        483294  JJDJKDS
2021-03-08  4341421         43243   AFADS
2021-03-08  134241          453454  FAFDS
```

df_today

```
date        codigo_cliente  amount  cliente_ciudad
2021-03-10  231321          31312   JSJDAS
2021-03-10  324122          424234  ADASDA
2021-03-10  31423241        42423   AFLAJS
2021-03-10  918492          324234  LADAJF
2021-03-09  219381          31893   JSFLA
2021-03-08  43497592        483294  JJDJKDS
```

I need a dataframe that has all the `df_today` records regardless of the common records between `df_today` and `df_history`. I don't know if dropduplicates handles some way or maybe a merge. The result would be:

```
date        codigo_cliente  amount  cliente_ciudad
2021-03-10  231321          31312   JSJDAS
2021-03-10  324122          424234  ADASDA
2021-03-10  31423241        42423   AFLAJS
2021-03-10  918492          324234  LADAJF
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should union the dataframes, then use some `max(date)` function, maybe grouping by `codigo_cliente`... Or just query for `date == '2021-03-10'`

Comment: Are you trying to find  all rows in `df_today` that are not present in `df_history`?

Comment: I need to leave the resulting df, with all the values ​​of df_today but removing the values ​​of df_today that are already in df_history

Comment: check out `pyspark.sql.DataFrame.exceptAll`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`exceptAll`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.exceptAll.html?highlight=except#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.exceptAll) or [`subtract`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.subtract.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.subtract) depending on how you want to treat duplicates.